# Function template won't work with string literals

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

Background:

I'm working on a query DSL that'll parse expressions with `==`, `<`, etc., and return filter objects via operator overloading.

Problem:

My template method is failing when used with a string literal. I've tried providing specific instantiations of the template taking both `std::string`, and `char` but neither seems to work.

The code is below. The line causing the problem in main is marked with a comment. Alternative solutions I've tried are commented out within the code.

A runnable repl of the same code can be found [here](https://repl.it/repls/BubblyIntentionalMachinelanguage).

I do know that manually wrapping the string literal with `std::string("text")` will work, but I want to be able to use plain string literals, if at all possible.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Filter;

struct Field
{
    Field(const std::string &val): name(val) { }
    Field(std::string &&val): name(std::move(val)) { }
    std::string name;

    // template <signed N>
    // Filter<std::string> operator==(const char (&val) [N]);

    template <typename T>
    Filter<T> operator==(const T &val);
};

template <typename T>
Filter<T> Field::operator==(const T &val)
{
    return Filter<T>{ *this, val, "==" };
}

// template <signed N>
// Filter<std::string> Field::operator==(const char (&val) [N])
// {
//   return Filter<std::string>{ *this, std::string(val), "==" };
// }

// template <>
// Filter<std::string> Field::operator==<std::string>(const std::string &val)
// {
//     return Filter<std::string>{ *this, val, "==" };
// }


template<typename T>
struct Filter
{
    Field f;
    T val;
    std::string op;
};

int main() {
  Field f1 { "field1" };
  Field f2 { "field1" };
  std::cout << (f1 == 1).val;
  std::cout << (f1 == "Hello").val;  // <--- the source of my problems
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue is that c-array is not copyable, so

```cpp
Filter<char [6]>{ *this, val, "==" }; // Error
```

Your overload is correct, but `Filter` needs to reordered and defined *before* your `operator==` overload. The overload returning `Filter<T>` is dependent on `T`, and so in that case `Filter`'s definition can be postponed. But when you return `Filter<std::string>` the compiler needs an actual definition of `Filter` up front.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Filter;

struct Field
{
    Field(const std::string &val): name(val) { }
    Field(std::string &&val): name(std::move(val)) { }
    std::string name;

    template <std::size_t N> Filter<std::string> operator==(const char (&val) [N]);

    template <typename T>
    Filter<T> operator==(const T &val);
};

template<typename T>
struct Filter
{
    Field f;
    T val;
    std::string op;
};

template <typename T>
Filter<T> Field::operator==(const T &val)
{
    return Filter<T>{ *this, val, "==" };
}

template <std::size_t N>
Filter<std::string> Field::operator==(const char (&val) [N])
{
   return Filter<std::string>{ *this, std::string(val), "==" };
}

int main() {
  Field f1 { "field1" };
  Field f2 { "field1" };
  std::cout << (f1 == 1).val;
  std::cout << (f1 == "Hello").val;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/371619d64496ad12)

Comment: +1 wow. It seems ... moving the Filter definition UP, before the `operator==` was all I needed to do. Could I trouble you to explain why that is?

Comment: If anyone else knows why the re-ordering was needed, speak up - I'd be happy to edit it into the answer and then accept it :-)

Comment: `Filter<T>` depends of `T`, so definitions might be postponed whereas `Filter<std::string>` doesn't depend of `N`, so definition should be known.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll edit the answer to include that when I'm back on a computer. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is specialize `Filter` for the case when `T` gets deduced to a `char[N]`.  Adding

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct Filter<char[N]>
{
    Field f;
    std::string val;
    std::string op;
};
```

Will cause `Filter<T>{ *this, val, "==" }` to call the above specialization and it will use a `std::string` to store `val`.

Comment: plus 1 - works perfectly. Thanks a TON for the info - will definitely keep this trick in mind for future use.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the C++17 tag, here is yet another option to solve this problem: [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Filter;

struct Field
{
    Field(const std::string &val): name(val) { }
    Field(std::string &&val): name(std::move(val)) { }
    std::string name;

    // note the use of auto here
    template <typename T>
    auto operator==(const T &val);
};

template <typename T>
auto Field::operator==(const T &val)
{
    // do not use Filter<T> here, or the deduction guide won't kick in
    return Filter{ *this, val, "==" };
}

template<typename T>
struct Filter
{
    Field f;
    T val;
    std::string op;
};

// ------- Deduction Guides -----------
template<typename T>
Filter(Field, T, std::string) -> Filter<T>;

// will tell the compiler to create a Filter<string> with a c-array argument
template<std::size_t N>
Filter(Field, const char(&)[N], std::string) -> Filter<std::string>;
// ------------------------------------

int main() {
  Field f1 { "field1" };
  Field f2 { "field1" };
  std::cout << (f1 == 1).val;

  // creates a Filter<string> instead of trying to 
  // create a Filter<const char(&)[6]> due to the deduction guide
  std::cout << (f1 == "Hello").val;
}
```